# Assembly language for Windows CE

Tags: windows, assembly, windows-ce

How can I write a program in assembly language for Windows CE (x86)?
Now I'm using VS2008 winth Windows CE 5.0 SDK, and my C++ programs runs fine. 
I tried to create an asm file with my code and to include it into project:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
extern "C" void clear(); 


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    clear(); 
    return 0;
}
```

clear.asm:

```
.586              ;Target processor.  Use instructions for Pentium class machines
.MODEL FLAT, C    ;Use the flat memory model. Use C calling conventions
.STACK            ;Define a stack segment of 1KB (Not required for this example)
.DATA             ;Create a near data segment.  Local variables are declared after
                  ;this directive (Not required for this example)
.CODE             ;Indicates the start of a code segment.

clear PROC
   xor eax, eax 
   xor ebx, ebx 
   ret 
clear ENDP 
END
```

Everything goes fine until I want to invoke WinApi function (MessageBox) form asm code.

```
    .DATA ;Create a near data segment. Local variables are declared after

    szMessageText       DB  "Hello world text", 0
    szMessageCaption    DB  "HWorld capt, 0

    .CODE ;Indicates the start of a code segment.
    clear PROC
    Invoke MessageBox, NULL, ADDR szMessageText, ADDR szMessageCaption, MB_OK
    clear ENDP
    END
```

It gives

> error A2006:undefined symbol : MessageBox

I added include path with Windows CE SDK libs for MASM:

C:\Program Files\Windows CE Tools\wce500\STANDARDSDK_500\Lib\x86

and tried to include coredll.lib, but there is no effect

```
includelib coredll.lib
```

So main question is:
**Where is my mistake? Can I write asm code with winapi functions?**

**Thaks for your answers!**

**-----------------------------------------------**

**UPD:**
Thanks everyone. 
I managed to build project by writing a proto defenition of function:

> MessageBoxW  PROTO hwnd:DWORD, lpText:DWORD, lpCaption:DWORD,
>   uType:DWORD

How can I avoid writing such prototypes for every function that I'll use?
As far as I understood i need .inc file with proto defenitions of the functions? 
Or somehow use function definitions that are in .h files?

Comment: Maybe MessageBoxA? That is, an ASCII variant of MessageBox which, in fact, is #defined in c headers: `#define MessageBox MessageBoxW` in case of `UNICODE` being defined and `#define MessageBox MessageBoxA` otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Invoke MessageBox, NULL, ADDR szMessageText, ADDR szMessageCaption, MB_OK
```

There is no function named MessageBox in the winapi.  There is MessageBoxA, a legacy function that takes 8-bit encoded strings, and MessageBoxW, a function that takes utf-16 encoded strings.  This is normally invisible when you write code in C, the preprocessor automatically translates the function name depending on whether you've got the UNICODE preprocessor symbol defined.

No such help when you write code in assembly, you'll have to pick the proper names yourself.  Btw, not actually sure if Windows-CE still supports the legacy function, you'll find out quickly.  The backgrounder MSDN article is [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I used PROTO to define MessageBoxW and everythig works fine. But how can I avoid using proto for every function that I'll use?

Comment: There are .inc files around the interwebs that have the declarations for winapi functions.  I think masm32 has them, you'll have to take a look.

Comment: There is proto of MessageBoxW in masm's user32.inc. "MessageBoxW PROTO STDCALL :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD"  I also switched to STDCALL calling convention in my asm code. But now it gives me this error "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MessageBoxW@16 referenced in function _clear@0", even with /coff flag for ml.exe

Comment: You are forgetting to link user32.lib

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So far everything is clear. I'll ask if will be any question.

Comment: IIRC,`MessageBox` is a `macro` which expands to `MessageBoxA` or `MessageBoxW` if `UNICODE` macro is defined.